# Why does chrome devtools show more than 6 simultaneous ajax requests?

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

According [to this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/) and a dozen different places chrome and most browsers limit simultaneous http requests to six per domain.

So what exactly am I seeing here?

[image: 18 simultaneous ajax requests]

Isn't that eighteen simultaneous ajax requests?

Here is a sampling of the timing details:

The first request:
[image: First request is mostly waiting]

The eighth request:
[image: The eighth request is mostly waiting]

All the requests I've looked at reflect something similar.

What's going on?!

Comment: Given the information in your link, have you checked if the requests are HTTP/1.0?

Comment: Or if you look in the timing details tab, are the later requests spending some time in the Blocking state?

Comment: (Click the name of a request, then click the "Headers" or "Timing" tab to check these things)

Comment: @RussellZahniser as you can see in my edit the Timing doesn't show anything blocking or queuing (it simply reflects what's in the first chart). However, I notice that if I hover over any one of the bars on the timing chart it shows the end-to-end total being significantly larger than the sum of the parts.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsNz8/) testing this. For me on Chrome on a Mac, it does exactly what you expect (six requests send immediately, the rest are Blocking). Without seeing your code I have no way of knowing why your case is different.

Comment: @RussellZahniser ok that clarifies things quite a bit actually if you look at the network tab on the fiddle. As you said, the timeline view shows when its queued, not when the connection is made. In your example fiddle puts a 2s wait on responses so the total times (by hovering over the timeline) are 2s, 4s, 6s respectively with the timeline details showing a 2s wait. In my case the request is taking ~650ms which is small enough the delay doesn't seem too big. If you can edit this into your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bar for a request on the timeline starts when the request was enqueued, not when it was sent. If you inspect the [timing](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#resource_network_timing) for one of the later requests (by clicking the name and then the Timing tab) you will probably see that it was Blocking for some amount of time before it was Sending.

```
code
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsNz8/) demonstrating this. The requests are sent in batches of six:

[image: network timeline]

... and the later requests show a Blocking time before they are sent:

[image: timing details for one batch]

Comment: See my edit. As far as I can tell most requests all spend a few ms sending, hundreds waiting, and a few ms receiving - just like you would expect with a regular non-queued http request.

Comment: Weird that I still don't get that Blocking bar, but I get similar numbers when hovering over the full bar in the timing chart.